# How do i execute javascript that was loaded from the DOM

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, domdocument

I am trying to execute a function in a javascript that has been loaded via the DOMDocument.
For instance:

```
'on page load
Webbrowser1.navigate("a htmldocument with a div called mainDiv")
```

Then later:

```
mDoc = WebBrowser1.Document
Dim mainDiv As IHTMLDOMNode = mDoc.DomDocument.getElementById("mainDiv")
mainDiv.innerHTML = (IO.File.ReadAllText("a file with just a div and script"))
'File has no html, head and body tags
```

So now i need to execute the script that was loaded retrospectively into mainDiv.
i've tried:

```
Webbrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("onLoadScript")
```

...but as far as i can gather, this method sees only the DOM loaded from the navigate event.
I'm hoping that there is a way of executing a script by accessing the DOMDocument.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try injecting a script that calls your dynamic script, dynamically. This bypasses the .InvokeScript function

```
HtmlElement headtag = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scripttag = WebBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement scriptelm = (IHTMLScriptElement)scripttag.DomElement;
scriptelm.text = "onLoadScript();";
headtag.AppendChild(scripttag);
```

Comment: I got this to work by substituting onLoadScript(); with alert('Hi'); so I get the concept however even though I can see the script by checking the innerHTML in mainDiv it still says it cannot be found. The same applies if I create an <input> button and call it like that however if i navigate to the html the button works.

Error: The value of the property 'onLoadScript' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Comment: Whilst the answer above didn't work out of the box for me. It did lead to the answer for me. I put an id='loadScript' on the script tag and went looking for it with GetElementByid('loadScript'). Once found I assigned it as above. The important thing was to change 'scriptelm.text = "onLoadScript();";' to 'scriptelm.text = scriptelm.text;'